# C++: Array that flexible and able to store multiple data types

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

I'm currently working on a C++ library, and I'm making an array class that just act just like vector and able to store multiple types of data. However, I met some problem and trying to fix them but I failed. I have shorten my code to make it easier to view and understand.

Below is my code:

```
class Char
{
public:
    Char()
    {
    }
    Char(char value)
    {
        v = value;
    }
    Char(Char& value)
    {
        v = value.val();
    }

    char val()
    {
        return v;
    }
private:
    char v;
};
class Int
{
public:
    Int()
    {
    }
    Int(int value)
    {
        v = value;
    }
    Int(Int& value)
    {
        v = value.val();
    }

    int val()
    {
        return v;
    }
private:
    int v;
};

class Array
{
private:
    class ArrayDef
    {
    private:
        enum class Types
        {
            Char,
            Int
        };
        union ArrayTypes {
        public:
            Char CharV;
            Int IntV;

            ArrayTypes()
            {
            }
            ArrayTypes(Char value)
                : CharV(value)
            {
            }
            ArrayTypes(Int value)
                : IntV(value)
            {
            }

            ~ArrayTypes()
            {
            }

            void assign(const ArrayTypes& value, const Array::ArrayDef::Types& type)
            {
                if (type == Types::Char)
                    CharV = value.CharV;
                else if (type == Types::Int)
                    IntV = value.IntV;
            }
        };

    public:
        mutable Types tp;
        mutable ArrayTypes v;

        ArrayDef()
        {
        }
        ArrayDef(const ArrayDef& value)
        {
            v.assign(value.v, value.tp);
            tp = value.tp;
        }
        ArrayDef(Char value)
        {
            v.assign(value, Types::Char);
            tp = Types::Char;
        }
        ArrayDef(Int value)
        {
            v.assign(value, Types::Int);
            tp = Types::Int;
        }

        Char getChar()
        {
            if (tp != Types::Char)
                throw(-1);
            return v.CharV;
        }
        Int getInt() const
        {
            if (tp != Types::Int)
                throw(-1);
            return v.IntV;
        }

        void operator=(ArrayDef value)
        {
            v.assign(value.v, tp);
            tp = value.tp;
        }
    };
    mutable ArrayDef* v;
    mutable int l = 0;

public:
    Array()
    {
    }
    ~Array()
    {
        delete[] v;
    }

    int len() const
    {
        return l;
    }

    void add(const ArrayDef& value)
    {
        ArrayDef* temp = new ArrayDef[l + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            temp[i] = v[i];
        l++;
        v = temp;
        v[l - 1] = value;
    }

    ArrayDef operator[](int value)
    {
        return v[value];
    }
};
```

I have created `Char` and `Int` classes that stores single type (I'm doing this to emulate classes in my library).

I have also created the main `Array` class that are able to store `Char` and `Int` classes' type. There are also an union `ArrayTypes` inside a class `ArrayDef` that are below private access specifier of the `Array` class.

Below is my driver code:

```
int main()
{
    Int i(100);
    Char c('a');
    Array arr;
    arr.add(i);
    arr.add(c);
    std::cout << arr[0].getInt().val() << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[1].getChar().val() << std::endl;
}
```

The first line of the output is wrong but the second line of the output is correct. Why would this happen and how to fix it?

Because of some technical issues, I'm unable to use STL.

Any answers is appreciated. Thank you. Peace.

Comment: Start again, create a base class that defines all your common functionality then derive type differences from the base class.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your code, one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables as they are changed by your program, and observe your program's logical flow, what observations did you make? This is exactly what a debugger is for, to determine what your program actually does. Knowing and being able to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. If you don't know how to use a debugger, you should use this as an opportunity to learn how to use one.

Comment: I'm unable to use STL so I can't use vector

Comment: @HaiQin _"Because of some technical issues, I'm unable to use STL."_ Can you elaborate about these issues please!

Comment: Is [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)/[`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) forbidden?

Comment: Ahah thank you Sam Varshavchik I will try

Comment: Hi @πάνταῥεῖ, Actually I can't use STL because this library is for all of the beginners and a lot of the beginners don't understand STL so they can only use it without knowing how it works.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, read my answer in the comment above (I can't tag two person at one time)

Comment: OK thx, I will use STL

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I should hope not! That's precisely what should be used here - _iff_, it turns out, a polymorphic array is really what is needed, which might not really be the best design in reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment operator,

```
    void operator=(ArrayDef value)
    {
        v.assign(value.v, tp);
        tp = value.tp;
    }
```

assigns `value.v` with whichever type `*this` has, and only afterwards changes the type of `*this`, possibly leaving the array in an inconsistent state.
This is particularly bad in your case since your default constructor doesn't initialise `tp`, leading to undefined behaviour on the first assignment.
You need to either transpose these two lines, or `v.assign(value.v, value.tp)`.

Even better would be to move the type-tracking into the union and make it private.

Or, you know, use the standard library and teach something your students will have use for later, and which they can learn more about in their literature.